# Delete unnecessary records from child table by using parent table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete

I have below two table,

tableA has,

```
primary key and a 
date field
```

tableB has,

```
id : primary
table1-id : primary key of tableA
val1,val2,val3 are used to store numerics.
```

Here we can have up to two rows in tableB for every entry in tableA.
But due to some problems there are more than two records have been inserted in tableB for every tableA rows.

I want to perform a migration task here to remove every extra entry from tableB.

I tried to write procedure but some how not able to perform required job.

tables are as below,

[image]
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I removed conflicting tags `mysql` and `sql-server` and added the generic `sql`tag. Please add only the tag that corresponds to your RDBMS.

Comment: You've tagged 2 very different RDBMS products here, what are you really using? Also, someone with 800 reputation should know how to show your attempts, and that data should never be an image. Please correct your tags  and take the time to edit your post so we can consume your information, and show us the expected results you are after. help us help you.

Comment: Our product supports both the database, that's why I have mentioned both databases.

Comment: As a result, here I just want to have only two entries in tableB for every tableA rows.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: *"Our product supports both the database"* but it's unlikely the code will be the same between the 2 across your application. Neither completely support ANSI SQL, and the parts they do support *can* be very different. MySQL SQL and T-SQL can be very different dialects.

Comment: What defines which are the "extra entry" in table B? There are no duplicates

Comment: mySql version:5.7.23

Comment: @Nick if tableB has more than two rows then we need to delete such records which has all three fields val1,val2 and val3 contains -1 data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments it seems this should do what you want. It deletes all entries from `tableB` where the 3 `val` values are all `-1` and the `id` value has at least 3  corresponding rows in `tableB`:

```
DELETE FROM tableB
WHERE val1 = -1 AND val2 = -1 AND val3 = -1
AND `table1-id` IN (SELECT `table1-id`
                    FROM tableB 
                    GROUP BY `table1-id`
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2)
```

In MySQL, to work around the

> Error Code: 1093 You can't specify target table 'tableB' for update in FROM clause

issue, replace `tableB` in the subquery with `(SELECT * FROM tableB) b` i.e.

```
DELETE FROM tableB
WHERE val1 = -1 AND val2 = -1 AND val3 = -1
AND `table1-id` IN (SELECT `table1-id`
                    FROM (SELECT * FROM tableB) b
                    GROUP BY `table1-id`
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2)
```

This query will also work in SQL Server.

Comment: getting error as,
Error Code: 1093
You can't specify target table 'tableB' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @Mahesh in MySQL you can work around that issue by replacing `tableB` in the subquery with `(SELECT * FROM tableB) b` (that query will still work in SQL server too)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL-Server, you could use `row_number()` and a updateable common table expression for this:

```
with cte as (
    select row_number() over(partition by [table1-id] order by id) rn from tableB
)
delete from cte where rn > 2
```

You don't needf to involve the parent table. Just rank the records in the child table within groups having the same `table1-id`, ordered by `id`, and delete every record with a rank strictly greater than 2.